# How to save SOM net model in pyclustering?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-computing, pickle, unsupervised-learning

Model SOM net can not save by pickle, Python throw exception ValueError ctypes objects containing pointers cannot be pickled. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved in pyclustering 0.8.2:

```
import pickle
from pyclustering.nnet.som import som, type_conn
from pyclustering.utils import read_sample
from pyclustering.samples.definitions import SIMPLE_SAMPLES

sample = read_sample(SIMPLE_SAMPLES.SAMPLE_SIMPLE1)
network = som(1, 2, type_conn.grid_four)
network.train(sample, 100)

dump_network = pickle.dumps(network)
network = pickle.loads(dump_network)
```